# Is there relative CSS locator for Selenium?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, xpath

Suppose I'm looking for some **div** elements under **#myPage** element.
My goal is to use CSS selectors and limit the search only to **#myPage** descendants.

Using Selenium XPath locators I can write something like this:

```
WebElement page = driver.findElement(new By.ById("myPage"));
....
List<WebElement> item = page.findElements(new By.ByXPath(".//div"));
```

However, trying to use CSS yields all **divs** in documents, not only descendants of **#myPage**:

```
WebElement page = driver.findElement(new By.ById("myPage"));
....
List<WebElement> item = page.findElements(new By.ByCssSelector("div"));
```

The big difference is the `.//` prefix that makes the XPath expression relative. I couldn't find similar property in CSS syntax, and I wonder if it's even possible.

P.S.
I know I can use `#myPage > div` expression, but then I couple the page lookup operation with the lookup of its descendants, which is not always desirable.

Comment: i would try this: driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#myPage div"))

anyway, your first operation is looking for the page with the certain ID. and second operation - is looking for the elements on the page ('div' descedants). "#myPage div" cssSelector seems to unite your operations

Comment: Thank you for your response but coupling these operations is not always wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality doesn't exist yet. There's a similar feature being proposed in Selectors API level 2 for DOM, and codified in Selectors level 4 as [relative selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relative), but I don't know if Selenium will ever implement such a feature.

If you must perform a relative lookup, XPath is your only option for now.