# Getting direct child element in protractor using chaining

Tags: javascript, xpath, css-selectors, protractor

I thought there was a way to chain locators and get a direct child doing so. So for example, say I have the following html structure

```
<tab title="my tab">
    <div _ngcontent-cjx-7>
        <div class='my other content'>...</div
    </div>
</tab>
```

I have a parent ElementFinder

```
var myTab = element(by.css('tab[title="my tab"]'));
```

But I need to select that div.  This doesn't work for me, but I thought I had seen something similar to this.

```
var myTabsDiv = myTab.$(' > div');
```

Is there a way to do this without falling back to xpath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is *no way to refer to the current node in CSS selectors* in general.

You have three options:

- violate the DRY principle a bit and repeat the parent locator:

  ```
  var myTabsDiv = myTab.$('tab[title="my tab"] > div');
  ```
- or revert to XPath location technique:

  ```
  var myTabsDiv = myTab.element(by.xpath('./div'));
  ```
- or, this is Protractor-specific: get the [`locator()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.locator) of the parent element and concatenate to make a new CSS selector:

  ```
  var myTabsDiv = myTab.$(myTab.locator().value + ' > div');
  ```

I've got a similar problem recently:

- [Using CSS selectors instead of XPath locators when searching through siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229515/using-css-selectors-instead-of-xpath-locators-when-searching-through-siblings)

Comment: I thought so. I thought I had seen an example of what I had shown and that protractor had some secret sauce to do that. I'm cool with this solution.

Comment: @Machtyn wait, I think I have the 3rd option. Could you please check if it works for you?

Comment: @Machtyn sorry, `.key` should be `.value` - fixed - works for me :)

Comment: Your update works with the myTab.locator().value ...  I'm not sure if that's "easier" and I suppose some testing would need to be made as to whether or not it is faster than using the xpath solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's been well over a year since I asked this question and it is still getting some views. Using `locator().value` has been very good. But it isn't foolproof. Particularly when generating ElementFinders dynamically. For instance, `element(by.css('tab[title="my tab"]')).element(by.css('.my.other.content')).locator().value` will only return `.my.other.content`.

In my project, for my Page Object classes, I'm using a string to hold the locator and then exposing the ElementFinder object publicly.

Suppose we have a page with the following structure:

```
<tab title="my tab">
    <div _ngcontent-cjx-7>
        <div class='my other content'>...</div
    </div>
    <div id="shopping-cart"> ... </div>
    <div class="pricing">
        <div class="sub-total">...</div>
        <div class="tax">...</div>
        <div class="total">...</div>
    </div>
</tab>
```

My typescript page object might look like the following:

```
export class TheTab {
    private static myTab = 'tab[title="my tab"]';
    private static otherContent = '.my.other.content';
    private static shoppingCart = '#shopping-cart';
    private static subTotal = '.pricing > .sub-total';
    private static tax = '.pricing > .tax';
    private static total = '.pricing > .total';

    public static myTabEl = $(TheTab.myTab);
    public static otherContentEl = $(`${TheTab.myTab} ${TheTab.otherContent});
    public static shoppingCartEl = $(`${TheTab.myTab} > ${TheTab.shoppingCart});
    public static subTotalEl = $(`${TheTab.myTab} > ${TheTab.subTotal});
    public static taxEl = $(`${TheTab.myTab} > ${TheTab.tax});
    public static totalEl = $(`${TheTab.myTab} > ${TheTab.total});
}
```

If needing an ElementFinder to be generated dynamically, then exposing a string may be necessary or providing a function to build and return the ElementFinder using the private strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath selectors is not a better choice as it slows down the element finding mechanism.

It will be very simple with [protractor-css-booster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster) plugin.

Download the plugin with

```
npm install --save protractor-css-booster
```

Add the plugin in your configuration file:

```
exports.config = {
  // ... the rest of your config
  plugins: [
    {
      // The module name
      package: "protractor-css-booster"
    }
  ]
};
```

Now, you can find your element like:

```
const divElement=element(by.firstChildOf('tab[title="my tab"]')); \\ returns the first div
```

You can also do some cool staffs with the plugin... check that out