# why locator() in Protractor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**source:**
http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.locator

```
// returns by.css('#ID1')
$('#ID1').locator()

// returns by.css('#ID2')
$('#ID1').$('#ID2').locator()

// returns by.css('#ID1')
$$('#ID1').filter(filterFn).get(0).click().locator()
```

What I believe is, excluding locator() also does the same job precisely; any cause or specific reason for this API?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I just use it for better error logging.  i.e.

```
it('should display the facility name', function () {
    var el = element(by.css('div.facilityName'));
    expect(el.isDisplayed()).toBe(true, 'Expected element ' + el.locator() + ' to be present and visible';
});
```

This returns in my console:

> Failures:
>
> 1) should display the facility name
>
> Expected false to be true, 'Expected By(css selector, div.facilityName) to be present and visible'.

Similarly, I use it with some helper functions (I use Protractor on Non-Angular, so I don't have the power of waiting for Angular synchronization available to me, so I use helpers like the one below:

```
/**
* @description Prevents test execution until the given element is present in the DOM
* @param [el] The element locator [time] The optional max timeout in ms [opts] The options
*/
Util.prototype.waitForElementPresent = function (el, time, opts) {
    var timeout = time || 0,
    counter = 0,
    verbose = opts ? opts.verbose : false;

    return browser.wait(function() {
        if (verbose) {
            process.stdout.write( !counter ? 'waitForElementPresent [' + el.locator() + '] ' : '.');
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        return el.isPresent();
    }, timeout).then(function () {
        if (verbose) {
            process.stdout.write('\n');
        }
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
it('should display the facility name', function () {
    var el = element(by.css('div.facilityName'));
    Util.waitForPresentAndVisible(el, 10000, {verbose: true});
    expect(el.isDisplayed()).toBe(true, 'Expected element ' + el.locator() + ' to be present and visible';
});
```

This prints out to the console:

> waitForElementPresent [By(css selector, div.facilityName)]..........

It's somewhat trivial, since the error would include the line and index of the failing code anyways.  But I find it helpful in some cases just to improve error logging.

I'm curious how other people use it.

Comment: Interesting use case! Posted one more.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much to use `locator()` for in real world, but here is one more use case - [avoid using `by.xpath()` in solving the "getting direct child of a current element" problem with CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38400290/771848) by getting the locator of the parent element and concatenating it with a direct child part to dynamically produce a complete CSS selector.

Comment: Ofcourse, we need for concatenation; protractor docs are behind stackoverflow :)